# How are datatypes that need more than 32 bits stored in a 32 bit OS

Tags: operating-system, size

How are datatypes that would need more than 32 bits stored in the system?

For example consider an unsigned int or a long which can have a value greater than 2 to the power of 32, how is it stored in the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any OS, or compiler, will use the number of bits that it needs. So if an OS or language has a need for 64-bit integers, it will just store such integers into an 8-byte representation.

There are standards for this, for integers as well as floating point numbers. See this article on Wikipedia for more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_numbering_formats

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bits in a 32-bit architecture to the number of bits the CPU registers are wide (There are some exceptions, such as floating point registers). This does not mean that the system can't handle datatypes larger than this, only that it must deal with these datatypes 32-bits at a time.

For example, machines have an "Add With Carry" instruction, which allows the machine to chain link multiple adds together so that arbitrarily sized numbers, say two 512-bit numbers, can be added in 16 steps (512/32).